# NSTextView Subclass - A4 Paper Look

Tags: cocoa, macos, subclass, nstextview

I am thinking about modifying my NSTextView to look like an A4 sheet. So basically a line drawn around the textContainer, but I don't know how this could be done...

Just in case no one understands what I mean, I've attached a screenshot :P

http://web.me.com/david.schiefer/a4.png

Thanks :)

Comment: Images should be embedded directly in your postings so their disappearance from your site doesn't make them disappear from SO.

Comment: This question has already been answered, so this is no longer necessary.

Comment: On the contrary. The purpose of SO is to provide a repository of solutions to programming problems using a Q & A format. That's why there are rankings for answers and accepted answers, to benefit others who are looking to solve a similar class of programming problems. So while embedding graphics on the site isn't of concern to you once you've had your answer, it's quite beneficial to the SO community as a whole. And it's actually better for you as a member as well, as it would make your question more valuable and thus likely to get voted up as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re likely to be wanting multiple pages, take a look at TextEdit (Format → Wrap to Page). Source code is in /Developer/Examples/TextEdit/.